# are there known issues with using "manage content and structure" to move sites within a site collection in SP 2010?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I would like to be able to use "manage content and structure" to move sub-sites within a site collection (SharePoint 2010).  For example I have a site that is right under my top level site and I would like to move it to be the child site of one of its' current peers.

There is some concern from admins that this creates a mess in the content DB, therefore all moves should be done using powershell export/import.

Can anyone tell me, technically, what happens when we use the move command in "content and structure" within a site collection and if there are known issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

Moving sub sites around within a site collection is no problem. They had the exact same command for moving sites in SharePoint 2007, and it worked.

When you click the button, what likely happens is there is a stored procedure that executes and moves all the data to the new location.

Databases are designed to handle the all these changes. You don't create more of a "mess" in the content database by moving a site around compared to the daily "mess" of adding new documents to document libraries all over the place. In fact doing a PowerShell export, delete old site, import process is probably more messy because the old site isn't 'deleted' it's moved to the "Recycle Bin". And some of the GUID's associated with the site will be changed on the import.

Basically my recommendation is use the Move command to move sites around as that's the easiest thing to do, and don't worry about the database, because it just works.